# How to redirect to previous page magento 2?

Tags: magento2

How to redirect to previous page from my custom action in magento 2

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In Your Controller write following code:

```
namespace Company\Module\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 

class Actionname name extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{      
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);

        // Your code

        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

This code works for me.Hope it will help you too.

Comment: Is their need to be xml file related to action in my module @ND17

Comment: @PranayK First tell me what is your issue, If your action does not use for any page render than no need to add XML file

Comment: if suppose i came to the list page when i need to go back, to home page i am getting the refererurl has list page url @ND17

Comment: When you need to go back any action are you perform? for example click on something?

Comment: yes I have Back link on click i need to get back to home page it is staying in list Page only. @ND17

Comment: than set backlink url to homepage url no need to create action for that and in that action previous url is list page url so it will stay in list page

Answer (score 21):

This could also be a valid answer in a shorter form
**Magento 2.0.4**

```
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;
class Fetch extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        // TODO: Implement execute() method.
        $this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
    }
}
```

Comment: The `execute` method is expected to return either a `Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface` or a `Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface`. Luckily the `_redirect` method does one of those so this is advisable: `return $this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());`

Comment: cool for the backend. works awesome with Magento 2.2.6.

Comment: This is the correct method to redirect to previous page. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Please use this code in your controller class:

```
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
$resultRedirect->setRefererUrl();
return $resultRedirect;
```

Here **resultRedirectFactory** is a class variable that can be inherited in your class from there parents.

To check if referral URL is set or not, Please print the $_SERVER variable first.
This code is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function execute(){
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    try{
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Redirection Sucessful.'));
    }catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());            
    }
    $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
    return $resultRedirect;
}
```