# Echoing SERVER HTTP_REFERER in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url

In native php we can display url referrer by `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`.

Now by Magento 2 i want to do the same thing, i have tried `echo $this->getRefererUrl();`, but it gives me **page not found** without error.

What is the proper way to display referer url in Magento 2?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94977/how-to-redirect-to-previous-page-magento-2

Comment: are you want to use in controller file?

Comment: Yes.... @Rakesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep `$this->_redirect->getRefererUrl();`  line and get Referer url in magento 2.

```
namespace Test\Modulename\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 

class Index name extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{      
    public function execute()
    {
        $referralUrl = $this->_redirect->getRefererUrl();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the controller, you can get the referer url by using `\Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface`.

For example: `vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/Edit.php`

```
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

    $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('customer_edit');
    if ($block) {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $_redirect */
        $block->setRefererUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl()); // Set referer url in your block.
    }
```

And then, the block we can get `$block->getRefererUrl()`